# Bootstrap 4 display a nav link when responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Nav Bar that is fully fuctional. My problem is on how to display a nav link when the page is responsive. Here's my code for reference:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 order-1 order-lg-0" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt2 mt-lg-0 text-uppercase">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">USD $ <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart (1)</a> <!-- This one must display at the right side of the navbar -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-link" id="removeOnCollapse">
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-search mt-auto mx-3" style="color: black;"
                                aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And here's what I want to expect:

[image]

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just use bootstrap flex `<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">...</div>`

For more reference read here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: 2 elements were displayed. I only need 1 element to display.